# Is it possible to adapt Selenium driver for usage with Selenoid?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenoid

E.g. I have ready-to-use Perl Selenium driver.
https://metacpan.org/release/Selenium-Remote-Driver

How to make it compatible with Selenoid and use Selenoid-UI ?

As far as I understand, Selenoid is based on Selenium 2.x version. But Selenium and Selenoid APIs are not compatible out-the-box. E.g. http://localhost:4444/status output is very different.

And when I try to run script for Selenium when Selenoid is running instead I got `Could not create new session: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` error.

Comment: Not sure about the perl binding . If you go to the Selenoid UI you will get the available capabilities that you have configured while setting up the Selenoid. Pick capabilities `curl -X POST 'http://selenoid:4444/wd/hub/session' -d '{ 
            "desiredCapabilities":{
                "browserName":"firefox", 
                "version": "latest", 
                "platform":"ANY",
                "enableVNC": true,
                "name": "this.test.is.launched.by.curl",
                "sessionTimeout": 30
            }
        }' `

Comment: As I have already said in respective issue - Selenoid is fully compatible with Selenium protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenoid is 100% compatible with Selenium protocol. All Selenium stuff is under `/wd/hub` route.

E.g. status API is `/wd/hub/status`. Just use `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` as Selenium URL for your tests and it should work.

Don't be confused that API returns less data under Selenoid.

[image]

E.g. according to [w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#dfn-status) for status API only two fields: `message` and `ready` are required

Thanks to @vania-pooh for replies in appropriate [github issue](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/issues/788)